# Return the loop at initialization of the foreach

Tags: php

I want to return at the init of the loop and when the count of array is 10, I need to print it out.
I am not sure if it is possible because, the return is out of the foreach loop.

Thanks in advice.

This is my current code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include_once('include.php');

$link=connect_db();
//butta in un array tutti i forecast e usa print_r(array_count_values($array));
//fai un foreach che per ogni previsione fa partire una query con variabi $limit che è il parametro di ff.previsione e il LIMIT 0,$limit


$get_values = "select previsione from forecast where data='2014-05-30'";
$res_values = mysql_query($get_values,$link);
$arr_vals = array();

while( $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_values) ) {
        array_push($arr_vals, $values['previsione']);       
    }

$new_array = array();
foreach ( $arr_vals as $key => $value ) {
    $limit = $value;

    $sel = "select min(op.cognome) as cogg,
                                      op.nome,
                                      op.cognome,
                                      op.ore_giornaliere_time,
                                      ff.ora,
                                      ff.previsione 
            from 
                 operatori op
            join 
                 turni_preconf tp on tp.tot_ore = op.ore_giornaliere
            join 
                 forecast ff on tp.inizio=ff.ora 
            where
                 ff.data='2014-05-30' and ff.previsione=$limit 
            group by op.cognome
            order by rand()
            limit 0,$limit";

$res_sel=mysql_query($sel,$link);


while( $er = mysql_fetch_array($res_sel) ) {

    echo $er['nome'].' '.$er['cognome'].':  '.remove_sec($er['ora']).'/'.sumatra($er['ora'], $er['ore_giornaliere_time']).'<br>';
    $nomecognome = $er['nome'].$er['cognome'];
    $orario = $er['ora'].'-'.sumatra($er['ora'], $er['ore_giornaliere_time']);

    array_push($new_array, array($nomecognome => $orario)); 

   //$new_array[$nomecognome] = $orario;


    }
}
var_dump($new_array);

echo'<br>';

$array2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $new_array);
echo count($array2);
if(count($array2) == 10){
        var_dump($array2);
    }
if(count($array2) != 10){
        //RETURN FROM ??? HELP...
    }

//butta nome cognome ora_inizio/ora_fine nel seguente modo [nomecognome]=>"ora_inizio-ora_fine" e rimuovi le chiavi duplicate preservando l'ordine
?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by return at the init of the loop?  Do you want to return after the first iteration and also print out the first 10 rows from your query?

Comment: for the beginning of the loop, I mean, that has to repeat the foreach to down, because the function array_merge print out the count of the numbers from 6 to 10, so I would like that only when they are 10 then print something, in this case the var_dump () . If it is not 10, he again by the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im still not realy sure what you mean, but it sounds like (for me) that you try to print out the array after it has exactly a length of 10. Else you want to run the foreach loop again until there are 10 elements in the array?

If this is what you mean then i would consider to put your foreach in a do{}while() loop.

Similar to this one:
Edit: [UNTESTED not sure if it works properly]

```
<?php
//some code

do{
      //code that should repeat until arraylength == 10 goes in here
      foreach(...)
      .
      .
      .
}while( count($array2) == 10 );

//no need for a second if statment,
//cause it only gets executet if we get out of the loop.
var_dump($array2); 

//some other code that gets executed
.
.
.
?>
```

And now on your code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
include_once('include.php');

$link=connect_db();
//butta in un array tutti i forecast e usa print_r(array_count_values($array));
//fai un foreach che per ogni previsione fa partire una query con variabi $limit che è il parametro di ff.previsione e il LIMIT 0,$limit


$get_values = "select previsione from forecast where data='2014-05-30'";
$res_values = mysql_query($get_values,$link);
$arr_vals = array();

while( $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_values) ) {
        array_push($arr_vals, $values['previsione']);       
    }

// START REPEAT until count($array2) == 10
do{
$new_array = array();
foreach ( $arr_vals as $key => $value ) {
    $limit = $value;

    $sel = "select min(op.cognome) as cogg,
                                      op.nome,
                                      op.cognome,
                                      op.ore_giornaliere_time,
                                      ff.ora,
                                      ff.previsione 
            from 
                 operatori op
            join 
                 turni_preconf tp on tp.tot_ore = op.ore_giornaliere
            join 
                 forecast ff on tp.inizio=ff.ora 
            where
                 ff.data='2014-05-30' and ff.previsione=$limit 
            group by op.cognome
            order by rand()
            limit 0,$limit";

    $res_sel = mysql_query($sel,$link);


    while( $er = mysql_fetch_array($res_sel) ) {

        echo $er['nome'].' '.$er['cognome'].':  '.remove_sec($er['ora']).'/'.sumatra($er['ora'], $er['ore_giornaliere_time']).'<br>';
    $nomecognome = $er['nome'].$er['cognome'];
    $orario = $er['ora'].'-'.sumatra($er['ora'], $er['ore_giornaliere_time']);

        array_push($new_array, array($nomecognome => $orario)); 

        //$new_array[$nomecognome] = $orario;
        }
    }
    var_dump($new_array);

    echo'<br>';

    $array2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $new_array);
    echo count($array2);

}while(count($array2) != 10) //END OF REPEAT
var_dump($array2);

//butta nome cognome ora_inizio/ora_fine nel seguente modo [nomecognome]=>"ora_inizio-ora_fine" e rimuovi le chiavi duplicate preservando l'ordine
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm not sure if this solution works.. do you try to edit my code for the right solution?

Comment: Sry I didn't tried the solution befor and might not work properly.